# Visual studio 2019 causing slow debugging and high usage of memory

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019

After short time while debugging my project using breakpoints Visual studio 2019 Professional almost stops responding and slows down very much. 
From activity manager I noted an ever increasing memory usage that could be the cause.

Debugging the same project using Visual Studio 2015 is instead very fast. Haven't tried 2017.

I have checked "Enable just my code".

My project is just plain C# without DB and Web.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But the thing you are asking for assistance is not to solve a programming, an algorithm or a pattern issue with some code. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: Actually, you can ask about programming tools here, according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment my problem. My problem is that I have a solution that debugs smootly on VS 2015 and slows down VS2019. My goal is to debug smoothly my solution. My difficulty is that I can't. So far I have checked "Enable just my code" (as I made in VS2015). This is not a specific line of code issue, it slows down if I put a breakpoint in every point of my solution. Which"Question I avoid asking" I have stumbled into? Thanks.

Comment: What is your code? Have you the same problem all over this code from the Main entry point first line or only in some part? Have you the same problem with all projects or this one only? Have you the problem only with one type of project (.NET Framework, .NET Standard, Core, Forms, Console, ASP...) or with all types? Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall VS2019? Have you try on another computer? What is your OS and the version (Windows 7/8/10, Linux, Apple...)? ...

Comment: My code is plain C# with Windows Forms, as I staded no web nor DB, Yes I have already reinstalled VS19, the slowing down appears every time I try do debug it everywhere, it does not seems to be related to specific code. Thanks.

Comment: *What is your OS and version? Have you try on another computer or another OS on your computer?*

Comment: Windows 10 (I think it is the only OS supported). No, I haven't tried other PC, I haven't any other PC with Win10 to install VS2019 to try debugging my solution.

Comment: Not installed yet but VS2019 works on Windows 7-SP1 or higher. Have you tried VS2017? It is more stable and safer since VS2019 is new born. If you don't need Core 3 or C# 8, you may use it for the moment. What is your CPU, motherboard, memory, hdd...? Have you tried to debug in safe mode?

Comment: Hi, do it make any difference if you go `Debug menu=>Options=>Symbols` to choose `Load only specified modules`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't found anymore VS2017 on microsoft.com. "Debug menu=>Options=>Symbols to choose Load only specified modules" does not resolve the problem. I have Intel Core I7 with 4 cores and 16Gb RAM in a DELL Latitude 5590. Thanks.

Comment: @Beorne You can find free VS2017 link [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) to check if same issue occurs in VS2017. And it could be better if you create a new project and debug it, still very last? Maybe this issue has something to do with project properties but I'm now not sure about it. I will track this issue and if there's any update, feel free to let me know :)

Comment: @Beorne Hi friend, is this issue resolved by the answer below? Hmm, I'm not certainly sure about this, but if this issue is resolved by that answer, please consider accepting it as answer to share the useful info ! See [one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It just a reminder :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While debugging I realized that slow debugging was related to Diagnostic Tools.

When VS 2019 slowed I stopped debugging, open Diagnostic Tools Window Tab and in Setting (gear) I checked / unchecked, when necessary, the checkboxes 'Memory Usage' 'CPU Usage'.

Finally, I solved unchecking 'Enable Disgnostic Tools While Debugging' in Options ---> Debugging ---> General.

VS 2019 version 16.3.6

Comment: I'm a web developer. 
I can report that the vs debugger slows after browser closing, stopping vs debugger session and restarting debugging session again. 
In this case I have to play with the 'Enable Disgnostic Tools While Debugging' in the 'Options' menu enabling/disabling it. 
That the only way to work. Hope Microsoft fixs the issue, asap.

Comment: Thanks you very much, this has resolved my problem, now debugging is smooth as has always been on VS2015.

Comment: @claudiosfr Hi friend, please consider reporting this issue to [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html), issue there will be sent to product team and they can help to check this.

Comment: @Lance Li-MSFT Good suggestion! I've just submitted the issue to MS with my firm profile. Thanks!

Comment: Hi all. 
I've just received good news from DC Forum: 
<goodnews>
A fix for this issue has been implemented in the Roslyn compiler (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/39341) and is being prepared for release. We'll update you once it becomes available for download.</goodnews>