# "Diagnostics session" timer seems very inaccurate

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

I am currently hunting a database transaction timeout issue and therefor use the timer provided by the `Diagnostic Tools` window as a rough estimation. After some time I realized that the timer is very inaccurate and even seems to become slower.

Has anyone else encountert this? Any way to make this timer more reliable?

[image]

Comment: IMHO that's wall clock time. How could it be inaccurate? Anyway, I think this is an XY issue. You're trying to solve a problem for which you think debug diagnostics session time is the solution. Tell us about the problem and we can work out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> After some time I realized that the timer is very inaccurate and even
>   seems to become slower.

I think that your debugger has some latency and poor performance issues. It is usually caused by some third party pakcages, caches,vs tasks or some extra options.

You could try my suggestions to troubleshoot your issue:

**Suggestion**

**1)** enable the option `Just My Code` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`

check the option `Load only the specified modules` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`Symbols`

**2)** delete vs component caches under `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxx\ComponentModelCache`

**3)** diable any third-party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions` or just use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to stat your VS and then test your project

**4)** If you use **VS2019 Enterprise**, disable `Enable IntelliTrace` under `Tools`->`Options`->`IntelliTrace`

**5)** There is [a known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58555473/visual-studio-2019-causing-slow-debugging-and-high-usage-of-memory) which the vs debugger behaves slowly because of turning on Diagnostic Tools and it has been fixed later.

So please **update** your VS2019 to the latest version in case some of the Diagnostic Tools fixes are ignored.